# Property 'exportJson' does not exist on type 'Connection'... while using JS Store

Tags: javascript, angular

```
connection.exportJson({
    from: "Table_Name",
    where: {
        Column1: some_value,
        Column2: some_another_value
    }
}).then(function() {
    console.log('Successfully exported');
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

// Trying to export the database using JSStore

Comment: Are you using TypeScript? If so it is likely because it does not know what type of object "connection" is. Did you [install the package from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsstore) in your angular app?

Comment: This [extensive article on JSStore in Angular](https://medium.com/jsstore/using-jsstore-in-angular-448333e91421) might also be of some use. Good luck!

Comment: jsstore package is installed,

Comment: connection object is not having exportJson property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exportJson` api has been removed from jsstore. If you are using v4 of jsstore, you can use [idbstudio](https://ujjwalguptaofficial.github.io/idbstudio/) to exportJson.

Otherwise have a look this thread - https://github.com/ujjwalguptaofficial/JsStore/issues/115. This provides code snippet for exportJson.